# Can an operator map a state into a number?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, linear-algebra, second-quantization

In [second quantization](https://www.tcm.phy.cam.ac.uk/%7Ebds10/tp3/secqu.pdf), it is often claimed

> $$
> a_{\lambda} | \Omega \rangle = 0, \cdots \tag{2.1}
> $$

where $a_{\lambda} $ is an annihilation operator, $| \Omega \rangle$ is the vacuum, $0$ is the number zero. $\cdots$ means another formula was omitted without confusing.

But, in (2.1) the left-hand side of is an operator and a ket, the right-hand side is a number. Is this mathematically/physically legitimate?

[For example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_(physics))

> In physics, an operator is a function over a space of physical states onto another space of physical states.

A number (in this case, 0, as the right-hand side of (2.1)) is not a state, neither ket/bra. Could the 0 on the right-hand side of the above equation be a null vector? By [the properties of null vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition_and_basic_properties)

> $0 |\mathbf{v} \rangle = | \mathbf{0} \rangle$

I can write the null vector as the number 0 multiplying an arbitrary vector. Hence, for a further operation
$$
\hat{O} | \mathbf{0} \rangle = \hat{O}  0 | \mathbf{v} \rangle = 0 \hat{O} | \mathbf{v} \rangle = 0 |\mathbf{v}' \rangle  =  | \mathbf{0} \rangle $$
where$
 |\mathbf{v}' \rangle := \hat{O} | \mathbf{v} \rangle 
$ and $\hat{O}$ is an arbitrary operator. $| \mathbf{0} \rangle$ is the null vector, not vacuum state. Everything looks consistent.

Comment: On the RHS of the first equation it is the zero vector. But $|0\rangle$ is *not* the zero vector (at least in the notation employed in e.g. the harmonic oscillator eigenbasis)!

Comment: $|0\rangle$ is undefined in the question! Do you refer to $|0_{\alpha} \rangle$ in the wiki? I think I tried to make the notation clear

Comment: If it is undefined, then the question is pointless, because it can mean anything...

Comment: Put in this way, $|0\rangle$ never appears in the question. Which one are you refer to?

Comment: What is your question, actually?

Comment: Could you clarity, where did you find $|0\rangle$ in the question?

Comment: Last comment from my side. The $0$ on the RHS means the zero vector, if $c: H\longrightarrow H$ maps vectors of a Hilbert space to the vectors of the same space.

Comment: OK. That answered my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are right and it is a null ket not a scalar zero on the right hand side of the first equation.

The inner product of a null ket with itself, and with every other ket, is zero. It follows that using simply the scalar zero in this context can be seen as a modest abuse of notation which does not lead to trouble because eventually inner products will be evaluated and they will be correct.